# Error with testing custom react hooks using jest and enzymne

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

When using custom hooks with jest and enzymne I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined'

Tried various things but nothing seems to work. Please help

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';

/* Utils */
import { useSystemContext } from '../../../utils/Context/SystemContextProvider';

/* Components */
import MenuStructure from './MenuStructure';

const Menu = () => {
    const [{ siteData }] = useSystemContext();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const openMenu = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const componentProps = {
        menuItems: siteData,
        openMenu: openMenu,
        open: open
    };

    return (
        <MenuStructure {...componentProps} />
    )
};

export default Menu;
```

Test

```
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Menu from '.';
import { testUseState } from '../../../utils/TestUtils';

describe('<Menu />', () => {
    let wrapper;

    it('calls setCount with 0', () => {

        wrapper = mount(<Menu />);

    });
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

       9 | import MenuStructure from './MenuStructure';
      10 | 
    > 11 | const Menu = () => {
         |                    ^
      12 |     const [{ siteData }] = useSystemContext();
      13
```

added useSystemContext as requested

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const SystemContext = createContext();

export const SystemContextProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <SystemContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </SystemContext.Provider>
);

export const useSystemContext = () => useContext(SystemContext);
```

This is works fine in the site when running

Comment: show your `useSystemContext`

Comment: Sure, here's the code

Comment: ```import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const SystemContext = createContext();

export const SystemContextProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
 <SystemContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
  {children}
 </SystemContext.Provider>
);

export const useSystemContext = () => useContext(SystemContext);```

Comment: Please use the edit button and edit your question, don't post it as an unreadable comment

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll add it now

Comment: Your example not helping, how you calling `useReducer`? How `reducer` looks like, I'm going to flag this question for closing, you need to add Reproducible example when asking a question: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: wow ok. I know its a complicated set up but thats not the point of the error. The question is how to test components with custom hooks as I get an error when I try. I'll try to recreate a simpler example to add as another question